# how to get day name from datetime database in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

how to query get day from this date on sql? September 29, 2000 is Saturday I just want to take the day

i use query `SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '2022-09-24')`

result success : |Saturday|

but if i use query `SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TGL_AKAD_MUR) from TABLE where FID_APLIKASI = 811213` this query error

how to solved my problem ?

Comment: Totally depends on the SQL engine you use.

Comment: i use Microsoft SQL Server Manajemen Studio

Comment: Have you even tried to find out yourself how to do this? Have you looked up date functions in SQL Server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 And as we see from the comment to the first answer you got, that you are mistakenly using a string data type to store the dates, have you looked up string functions in SQL Server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Ah, I see you just changed the question completely. `'TGL_AKAD_MUR'` is a string. Its first character is a T, then there is a G and so on. This string does not represent a date. You probably want to invoke `DATENAME` on a column named `TGL_AKAD_MUR` instead. So, remove the single quotes.

Comment: i have tried to remove the single quotes but still error

Comment: Then `TGL_AKAD_MUR` is not a date column. If it is a string column, you'll have to convert its value from string to date in order to invoke a date function like `DATENAME` on it. But as mentioned in the comments to Vignesh B's answer: Better change the table design and use the appropriate data type for the column in the first place.

Comment: If you fix your design, you fix your problem here. `ddMMyyyy` isn't a recognised date format (even when using a language that uses the date format `dmy`). You'll need to first fix your textual data to be in an **unambiguous** format (I recommend `yyyyMMdd`), remove any *bad* data (such as `20210229` or `20222319`) and then change the data type of your column to an appropriate data type (`date` seems correct here). Then `DATENAME` will work without issue. The problem isn't the function, or your SQL, it's your design.

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
DECLARE @TGLAKADMUR NVARCHAR(100)= N'24092022'
```

first you should change `DDMMYYYY` to `DD/MM/YYYY` with

```
SELECT  @TGLAKADMUR,CONCAT(LEFT(@TGLAKADMUR, 2),'/',RIGHT(LEFT(@TGLAKADMUR, 4),2),'/',RIGHT(@TGLAKADMUR, 4))
```

then you should use `convert(date,string,103)` to make your `Nvarchar` to `Date`

```
SELECT Convert(date,CONCAT(LEFT(@TGLAKADMUR, 2),'/',RIGHT(LEFT(@TGLAKADMUR, 4),2),'/',RIGHT(@TGLAKADMUR, 4)),103);
```

then use `DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date)`
as follows:

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Convert(date,CONCAT(LEFT(@TGLAKADMUR, 2),'/',RIGHT(LEFT(@TGLAKADMUR, 4),2),'/',RIGHT(@TGLAKADMUR, 4)),103))
```